# Editing a <p> without an id

Tags: javascript

I have a element with a child of an empty paragraph. That looks like this. [Photo for easier viewing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilG41.jpg)

```
<body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="true">
    <p><br></p>
        </body>
```

How do I edit the area between the two p's using javascript to what ever I want since there is no id on them.

```
var onlineContent = document.getElementsByClassName("cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders");
```

All I have so far is this.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object so you need to select with:

```
var onlineContent = document.getElementsByClassName("cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders")[0];
var onlineContentInner = onlineContentOuter.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
```

the 0-th (meaning first) element.

An alternative method is given with `document.querySelector(A_VALID_CSS_SELECTOR)` wich return only the first element found (equals `document.querySelectorAll(CSS_SELECTOR)[0]`).

A valid css selector would be `.cke_editable.cke_editable_themed.cke_contents_ltr.cke_show_borders`
and your element would be (using `document.querySelector`):

```
var onlineContentInner = document.querySelector(".cke_editable p");
```

There you have it.

Comment: An **array-like object** not an **array**.

Comment: And how do I change in between the two "p's" ? .innerHTML?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, yes, but for simplification. This question is obviously asked by a beginner, so I do not want to irritate.

Comment: @JohnApple , with `var onlineContent` correctly set, you could simply do `onlineContent.innerHTML = "I don't like online content.<br />Instead I preferably do smth. offline."`

Comment: @camelCaseNick `getElementsByClassName` can have multiple classes!

Comment: Oh boy. Gives me an error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined". Also, if I have multiple of these classes would that cause any problems?

Comment: @JohnApple What did you exactly write? Hopefully your CKEditor is not undefined...

Comment: if(autoOnlineContent){
            var onlineContent = document.getElementsByClassName("cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders")[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                onlineContent.innerHTML = "I don't like online content.<br />Instead I preferably do smth. offline.";
                
            },2000);
        }

Comment: It looks like `onlineContentOuter` would be undefined and it should be changed to `onlineContent` to match with the variable definition.

Comment: @JohnApple, try it with `document.querySelector(".cke_editable p").innerHTML`.

Comment: Not sure if this complicates things more but it has every new "text editor" in a new document. https://imgur.com/a/RCv3I

Comment: @JohnApple, yeah, but `document.querySelector(".cke_editable p")` is only the first one...

Comment: Yes but they all have the same class name.

Comment: @JohnApple, is there any difference between their classes, attributes, location etc. you could use in a css selector?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) you can try this :

```
$(".cke_editable p:first").html("The text has changed");
```

You can also read more about how jQuery :first Selector works here: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_first.asp

Comment: jQuery is using CSS synthax so it is nearly the same as `document.querySelector` you have no benefit from using jQuery. It is just yet another framework you have to understand, use, load etc... Don't recommend it.

Comment: I am assuming he already have Jquery installed since he is using CKEditor

Comment: I looked at CKEditor's site and it appears it doesn't require jQuery.

Comment: @John Since version 4.2 all CKEditor packages are shipped with Jquery  you just have to load the jQuery Adapter file in the page, in the following order: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>`
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>` [CKEditor 4 Documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery)

Answer (score 0):

It would be like this.

```
var onlineContent = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
onlineContent.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "Content between the p tags";
```

Reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp

Comment: `onlineContent.document` is undefined.